# What is the proper way for a sysadmin to be notified about each user connection and disconnection?

Tags: login, monitoring, logout

In order to watch a machine, I'd like to be notified
for example by e-mail each time any user connect to or
disconnect from the machine (even root)?

It is a Linux machine, but I am also interested if there
is a general way for BSDs too.

I am the admin of the machine but there are other admins too.

Thanks!

Comment: Similar question at [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179889/how-do-i-set-up-an-email-alert-when-a-ssh-login-is-successful), presuming you are talking about ssh.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly hack up something complicated using `tail -F` and `awk` but the easiest way is to use `perl`, so you can use the `File::Tail` module (to monitor the appropriate system log file) and one of the many mail-sending modules (such as `Mail::Send` or `Net::SMTP`) to send mail when it notices that a user has logged in.  or logged out.  or failed to login successfully. or whatever other event you want to be notified about.

The `File::Tail` module includes example scripts that already do about 90% of what you want, they can easily be adapted to suit your exact needs.

The exact log file to monitor varies from distro to distro, e.g. on Debian you'd monitor `/var/log/auth.log`, on some other distros it would be `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/messages`.

Note that freebsd doesn't have perl installed by default, but it is available with, e.g., `pkg add perl5.22`.  This only installs the basic perl language, you'd have to use CPAN to install library modules like `File::Tail` pr `Mail::Send`.